# How can I bulk update my mongo data to add a fixed level?

Tags: java, mongodb, migration

I recently changed a POJO from having all its typed properties to something free in a typed JSONObject field called *content*.

The problem is that all old documents map to the old POJO version, so they are stored like this:

```
{"_id":"ObjectId(value)","field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
```

Can I update all fields via a single mongo command so I can wrap all the content, except the id, so the result would be something like this:

```
{"_id":"ObjectId(value)","content":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}}
```

?

Or should I program a simple program that does it one by one? (as in iterating all values sort of manually adding the new *content* level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it creating a .js file to execute via mongo shell.

```
mongo myDb fixresults.js
```

The file is as follows:

```
for( var c = db.results.find(); c.hasNext(); ) {
    var full = c.next();
    var anon = db.results.findOne({"_id":full._id},{"_id":0});
    var n = {"_id":full._id,"content":anon};
    db.results.temp.insert(n);
}
```

This will insert the transformed value into the .temp collection, which you can rename later to replace the original.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no MongoDB commands that will allow you to restructure a document in this way. You'll need to write a program to fetch all of your documents one by one, update the structure, and then send the updated structure back to MongoDB.

Often the best way to do this is to write the modified documents to a new collection, and then drop the old collection when you're done.